# how to move view upside while entering any text in input field

Tags: ios, ipad, landscape

I have app i want that when user enters any data then view should slide up.
I am writing this code this code works fine in another app but not working in this app.I am following same way.

```
-(void)showAnimationBack{

    NSLog(@"Back Animation is Working");


    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 
                     animations:^{
                         self.subViewLand.frame = CGRectMake(0,-10,1024,768);


                     }];

}


-(void) showAnimationPests{


    NSLog(@" Animation is Working");


    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 
                     animations:^{
                         self.subViewLand.frame = CGRectMake(0,-200,1024,768);


                     }];


}
```

Comment: what is that subViewLand? UIView? is it allocated?

Comment: where u calling this methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    self.subViewLand.frame  = CGRectMake(0,-200,1024,768); // or to self.view.frame  = CGRectMake(0,-200,1024,768);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
        self.subViewLand.frame = CGRectMake(0,-200,1024,768); // or to self.view.frame  = CGRectMake(0,-200,1024,768);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

This code will work

Answer (score 0):

in textfielddidBeginEditing Method set view frame like this

```
 - (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
   [self.subViewLand setFrame:CGRectMake(0, -200, 320, 480)];
}
```

in textfielddidEndEditing Method set view frame as it is.

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    [self.subViewLand setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
}
```

It will definitely work. :)

Answer (score 0):

In `textFieldDidBeginEditing()` call the your method `showAnimationPests()` and similarly in `textFieldDidEndEditing()` call `showAnimationBack()` .

This will work fine for you.